# Converting pixel data into an image

Tags: image, pixel, gif, bmp

I am having pixel data of size 1030 bytes and i wish to convert it into an image for ex. GIF or BMP or any such. The data is one bit per pixel. I would like to dump it into an image 128X64 size with black and white pallette. Please help.
The data looks like below.

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

Comment: How did you try? I can figure that read each byte and convert to byte value (in range 0-255), you can restruct the image.

Comment: I opened a blank bmp in hex editor and placed these bytes in the data part of the byte stream but it doesn't seem to work. I also changed the other attributes like size and bits per pixel also in the format.

Comment: First, make sure your byte data fit with image size and **bit depth (bit per pixel)**. Also, take care about stride (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: @RamEvani ...or something like that. ;-) I'm actually able to decode the image, but as a weird, 90 degrees rotated, strip of 8 x 1024 pixels. With some massaging, the image can be reconstructed. See my answer below.

Comment: @haraldK I apologize for removing the data. I did not have any wrong intention. I got to know after posting the question that it is sensitive data related to our client which is why i tried to remove the data.Sorry once again.

Comment: @ImageDev I see. I have a hard time seeing that the posted data could potentially harm anyone, though... A fix could perhaps be to create new dummy data in the same layout and use my program to create new images? Anyway, if you really need to delete the question, I think you could flag the question for moderator attention, and explain why you would want it deleted.

Comment: @haraldK Thank you for understanding. For now, I will leave the data as it is. In case there is a need for it in future, I will do as you suggested. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is pixel data, and the image looks like this:

[image: Image output]

---

However, the image data isn't in a normal layout, so decoding it is a little more complex than usual.

1. First, the image data really is written as a long strip of data (this might make sense, if the output device is a printer, but isn't common in a graphical file format). The dimension is 8 x 1024:

[image: Strip]

2. Now that we see that the image data is rotated, and that each block of 8 pixels width is just appended to the previous parts of the image, we can re-assemble the data, to get the full image (now 64 x 128):

[image: Reassembled]

3. Finally, we need to rotate the image 90 degrees CCW to get the result (128 x 64, as shown above).

---

I've written a Java application to do it:

```java
public class BitmapTest {
    // Java by default uses inverse colors
    private final static int[] MONO_PALETTE = {0x00FFFFFF, 0x00000000};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Create "strip" data
        DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(DATA, DATA.length);
        SampleModel sm = new MultiPixelPackedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, 8, 1024, 1);
        WritableRaster raster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sm, buffer, null);

        IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(1, 2, MONO_PALETTE, 0, false, -1, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage strip = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

        // 2. Reassemble "strip" to full image
        BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(64, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics2D g = temp.createGraphics();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                g.drawImage(strip.getSubimage(0, 128 * i, 8, 128), 64 - 8 - 8 * i, 0, null);
            }
        }
        finally {
            g.dispose();
        }

        // 3. Rotate image -90 degrees
        int center = temp.getWidth() / 2;
        AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(-1, center, center);
        final BufferedImage image = new AffineTransformOp(xform, null).filter(temp, null);

        // 4. Write result to BMP (change to PNG if you like)
        ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("output.bmp"));

        // 5. Display it, if you like
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("BitMap");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(label);
                scroll.setBorder(null);
                frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    final static byte[] DATA = {
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x7E, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xA8, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0xAD, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xE1, (byte) 0xFB, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0xCF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x7F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x5C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0x1E, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1F, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be sure when there is no indication how it should look, but I'll have a go with this:

```
{ echo P4; echo 128 64; xxd -r -p image.bin - ; } | convert - result.png
```

[image]

In theory, I am writing a NetPBM header [(described here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) for a PBM file with P4 to say it is binary encoded. Then I put the width and height. Then I convert the hex to binary using `xxd`. The whole lot is made into a single compound statement with `{...}` and fed into ImageMagick and it is told to convert the incoming PBM file into a PNG.

Comment: Have you got the actual binary file please - rather than the hex dump?

Comment: If you can't share it, try replacing `xxd ... ;` in my command with `cat file.bin;`

Comment: The input I get is hex data and not in binary and i guess it will be the same as what xxd does even if it is converted to binary. I am suspecting byte order issues here as i too got the same image as the one you attached when i inserted this data in the data part in an empty bitmap file.

Comment: Can you show the actual image? Is it a 128x64 pixel display?

Comment: I am extremely sorry i will not be able to show the actual image as our company does not allow but yes it is a 128X64 display as you mentioned. I am attaching a screenshot of how it looks on the display.

Comment: I think i cannot attach files here.